# Two step construction. Useful or just a code smell?

Tags: ruby, context-injection

Normally I expect that once an object is constructed, it should be ready for use, period. No two step construction. If you need calling two constructors for using an object something is very wrong... right?

```
class Contact
  attr_accessor :auth_token

  def initialize(contact_hash)
     ...
  end

  def edit(...)
     auth_token.can! :read, self
  end
end

token = AuthorizationToken.new(session)
contact = SomeService.get_contact(...)

contact.edit(...)
# raise error because auth_token is not set

contact.auth_token = token

contact.edit(...)
```

The code above represents my current dilemma: I want **SomeService** to give me **Contact** objects, but I do not want that service to be concerned about an existing session, or authorization at all.

My current approach is adding this extra class:

```
class QueryService
  def initialize(session)
    token = AuthorizationToken(session)
  end

  def get_contact
    contact = SomeService.get_contact(...)
    contact.token = token
  end
end

contact = QueryService.new(session).get_contact(...)
contact.edit(...)
```

This solution gives me the most freedom to use authorization concerns inside the core domain object **Contact**, implement them in an external class **AuthorizationToken** and implement services that are not concerned about the current user session **SomeService**.

However the two step construction is killing me. It feels strange: An object that is not fully initialized for some operations???

This is not a plain case of dependency injection, but more exactly a context injection. So most of the articles about avoiding DI in Ruby do not really solve my problem. I am wondering if there is a **more Ruby way** to solve this, or this is just as clean as it can get.

Comment: This does seem a bit weird. Also, do you ever call `get_contact` from `QueryService`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Contact` class serves two purposes - storing contact data and doing some authorized requests - so yes it does violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

This could be fixed by splitting the `Contact` class into two - one maybe a `Struct` or  even a plain hash to store the data, and the second that has does the requests.

And I think the most *Ruby* way to do it would be to return hashes from `SomeService` and instantiate with `Contact.new(data, auth_token)` later on.

Comment: I've just added `self` to the call of auth token to show my use of ioc to reduce the burden of authorization logic. Actually `Contact` is not a plain storage model, but a domain aggregate root. I did not want to mention  DDD trying to make my question easier. I am more curious to find out if the use of two step initialization is a code smell.

Comment: After some experiments I quickly noticed that the authorization object in my example was a totally insane idea and clearly headed towards trouble. That was a very bad example!

Comment: Although this answer does not directly answer the question in the title, a two stage construction leads directly to breaking the SRP since there is a transition of what the object can do before and after the second initialization. A sure break of the SRP seems to indicate that two stage construction is actually a code smell

Comment: @SystematicFrank Oh! Well, from a DDD perspective the service should definitely return Value Objects and not Entities, and that should free the VO from the dependency on the token.